# GO111MODULE=on (error loading module requirements)

Tags: go

`go get -u github.com/junegunn/fzf` works fine but want to test the development branch like so:

```
gert@gert ~/ GO111MODULE=on go get -u github.com/junegunn/fzf@devel
go: finding github.com/junegunn/fzf devel
go: finding golang.org/x/crypto latest
go: finding github.com/smartystreets/assertions latest
go: finding github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs latest
go: finding github.com/smartystreets/goconvey latest
go: finding github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs v0.0.0-20181017120253-0766667cb4d1
go: finding golang.org/x/sys latest
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190328211700-ab21143f2384
go: gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1@v1.3.3: go.mod has non-....v1 module path "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock" at revision v1.3.3
go get: error loading module requirements
```

Not sure what is going on here? get the same result if I do

`GO111MODULE=on go get -u github.com/junegunn/fzf`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package `github.com/gdamore/tcell` which is required by `fzf` has `gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1` dependency. In version 1.3.3 of `go-sqlmock` they started to use go modules without version suffix and now explicit indication of the version no more working.

```
go get gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1
go: gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1@v1.3.3: go.mod has non-....v1 module path "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock" at revision v1.3.3
go: error loading module requirements
```

If you want to work on the devel package without updating its dependencies use `go get github.com/junegunn/fzf` without `-u` flag.

There is open pull request in `tcell` repository about this issue: https://github.com/gdamore/tcell/pull/267